# How to sort out records before certain a date

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datetime, datagrid

How can I sort out records from a DataGrid that are before a certain date, like 2014?

That's the value i put in my DataGrid:

```
((targetDate != DateTime.MinValue) ? ("'" + targetDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'") : "NULL")
```

now i need to "filter/sort out" all records that are before 2014.

This is how the Dateformat is:

```
targetDate = (tmp != "") ? DateTime.ParseExact(tmp, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture) : DateTime.MinValue;
```

that's in `tmp`:

```
tmp = BTQEntry.SelectToken("cq:deadline").Value<String>().Replace('T', ' ').Replace('Z', ' ');
```

Comment: Assuming your DateTime parse is working, you can use `targetDate < new DateTime(2014, 1, 1)`

Comment: Or even " targetDate.Year < 2014 "